# Hi, how to use `clojars` repo in Clojure 1.9.0 `clj` command's `deps.edn` file?

Tags: clojure

how to use `clojars` repo in Clojure 1.9.0 `clj` command's `deps.edn` file, just like the mvn repo:

```
{:deps
 {clj-time               {:mvn/version "0.14.2"}}}
```

I've tried the following but failed:

```
{:deps
 {some/clojars-repo {:clojars/version "1.0.0"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `clojars` to `mvn` and the `mvn` works for `clojars` also.

```
{:deps
 {some/clojars-repo {:mvn/version "1.0.0"}}}
```